# MediatR send generic type class

Tags: generics, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-3.0, mediator, mediatr

I've been trying to send generic type class via mediator.
I created a CreateSettingCommand class that accepts any model via:

```
var createUserCommand = new CreateSettingCommand<Database.Models.Product> { Setting = Product };
var result = await mediator.Send(createUserCommand);
```

I get the following error when I run it:

```
ArgumentException: The number of generic arguments provided doesn't equal the arity of the generic type definition. (Parameter 'instantiation')
```

This is my CreateSettingCommand class:

```
public class CreateSettingCommand<T> : IRequest<CreateSettingCommandResponse>
{
    public T Setting { get; set; }
}

public class CreateSettingCommandResponse : BaseResponse
{
}

public class CreateSettingCommandHandler<T> : IRequestHandler<CreateSettingCommand<T>, CreateSettingCommandResponse>
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext context;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor httpContext;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager;

    public CreateSettingCommandHandler(ApplicationDbContext context, IHttpContextAccessor httpContext, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.httpContext = httpContext;
        this.userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task<CreateSettingCommandResponse> Handle(CreateSettingCommand<T> request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var response = new CreateSettingCommandResponse();

        var currentUser = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(httpContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);

        if (currentUser != null)
        {
            try
            {

                // set value to generic class
                Type type = request.Setting.GetType();
                type.GetProperty("ActionBy").SetValue(type, currentUser.UserName);
                type.GetProperty("ActionOn").SetValue(type, DateTime.Now);
                type.GetProperty("ApplicationUserId").SetValue(type, currentUser.Id);

                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                response.AddError(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            response.AddError("Current logged in user not found.");
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

This is my Startup:

```
services.AddMediatR(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
services.AddScoped(typeof(IRequestHandler<,>), typeof(CreateSettingCommandHandler<>));
```

Any help would be appreciated!
p/s: this is a web application